# Parsing xml file from url and loop to get all urls in it using node.js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I'm using node module `xml2js`. My `xml` file is of the form.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="some url" ?>
        <rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
            <channel>
                <item>
                    <pubDate>Fri, 19 Sep 2014 18:00:08 GMT</pubDate>
                    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.example0.com</guid>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <pubDate>Fri, 19 Sep 2014 17:52:25 GMT</pubDate>
                    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.example1.com</guid>
                </item>
            </channel>
        </rss>
```

I want to get all the urls under `<item><guid isPermaLink="false">` as an array.

I'm trying out the code, but it is for a locally stored xml file. Also, I'm unable to get the urls.:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    xml2js = require('xml2js');

var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
parser.addListener('end', function(result) {
    console.dir(result);
    console.log('Done.');
});
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/foo.xml', function(err, data) {
    parser.parseString(data);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [sax-js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js) module to extract URLs you need.
The module you mentioned uses `sax-js` internally.

Here is the code (rough cuts):

```
'use strict';

var sax = require('sax');
var fs = require('fs');

var filePath = __dirname + '/' + 'foo.xml';
var isTextPending = false;

var saxStream = sax.createStream(true);
saxStream.on('error', function (e) {
  console.error(e);
});

saxStream.ontext = function (text) {
  if(isTextPending) {
    console.log(text);
    isTextPending = false;
  }
};

saxStream.on('opentag', function (node) {
  if(node.name === 'guid' && node.attributes.isPermaLink === 'false') {
    isTextPending = true;
  }
});

fs.createReadStream(filePath)
  .pipe(saxStream);
```

And the output is:

```
http://www.example0.com
http://www.example1.com
```

UPD:

To fetch XML from the internet to process it, use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module:

```
var request = require('request');

var href = 'http://SOME_URL.xml';

request(href)
  .pipe(saxStream);
```

Comment: Will this work if the xml file is sourced at a url instead of a locally available?

Comment: Yes, see the updated answer. Use the `request` module to get the readable stream